# Remove image after loading screen with animation, Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to show a splash screen between activities. For this I'm using a handler that loads an ImageView then sets the visibility to GONE after a certain amount of time.

I wanted to make it a bit more fancy and animate it with a loadAnimation. The problem I'm running into is once the handler ends the animation stops but does not remove the loading image from the screen. Instead it is just placed as a background for the whole activity.

I would like to know how to remove the splash image after the handler stops.

Below is my code:

```
private static final long SPLASHTIME = 3000;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    ImageView splash = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.splashscreen);
    final Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),R.anim.progress_anim);
    a.setDuration(1000);
    splash.startAnimation(a);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
             public void run() {
               a.cancel();
               splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        }, SPLASHTIME);
}
```

XML for splash image:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/splashscreen" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:src="@drawable/loading_circle"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

Comment: remove image in xml and set that image in oncreate.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare splash globally and not in oncreate().

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add visibility :gone in XML:ImageView

and make imageview INVISIBLE

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
a.setFillAfter(true);
```

to the end of your code inside your Runnable.